# Are all abstract methods in java declared with void return type?

Tags: java, abstract, void

Must all abstract methods in java be declared with void return type? 
i.e.

```
public abstract void myMethod();
```

instead of

```
public abstract myMethod();
```

What happens when the method is not declared with void return type?

I suppose that a method declaration as below is also wrong due to the existence of the 'scope' symbols.

```
public abstract void myMethod() {}
```

Kindly clarify my doubts, as I am still a beginner in this area.

Comment: can you declare a method as public abstract myMethod();?

Comment: `public abstract int getAnswer();` is valid and clearly not defined as void

Comment: return type is required in all java methods.. no matter if it's abstract or not

Comment: In order to be a method declaration it must have some return type, possibly void, regardless of whether it is abstract. Many abstract methods have non-void return types.

Comment: In the second line of code where is the return type of the method? Please consider researching the web before adding the question as the syntax of Java is explained in many websites.

Comment: You should ask yourself first (**not** others) - what is the meaning of method being declared abstract? How is that different from non-abstract method? When you answer these questions the answer to your question will become obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Must all abstract methods in java be declared with void return type?

No. You can give any return type.

> What happens when the method is not declared with void return type?

You must give a return type to a method. A method declared without any return type won't compile. A method signature comprises of - *method name*, *return type*, *list of formal parameters* if any, *list of type parameters* if any. You can't skip the first two.

> I suppose that a method declaration as below is also wrong due to the existence of the 'scope' symbols.

I guess you meant, "curly braces". Yes that would fail to compile. `abstract` methods can't have body.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when the method is not declared with void return type?

In Java, You should declare what a method returns in it's signature. It can be void or some other object type or primitive type. It doesn't matter whether it's a abstract method or normal method.

> Must all abstract methods in java be declared with void return type?

No, They can declared to return any object type, primitive type and, also declared to return `void` to indicate it return nothing.

> I suppose that a method declaration as below is also wrong due to the
>   existence of the 'scope' symbols.
>
> ```
> public abstract void myMethod() {}
> ```

Yes, it's wrong. An abstract method can't have method body. It's a compilation error.

Comment: "No, They can declared to return any object type." - Actually it doesn't have to be an *object*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun : Yes, I do mean any type, Object or primitive. Anyway Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can put your own return type in the method declarations of abstract classes

Answer (score 0):

Whether a method is `abstract` or not has no bearing on a methods return type.

An `abstract`method can have either a void or non-void return type:

```
public absract int getValue();
public absract void doSomething();
```

Abstract only determines that the current method/class will be defined by some future subclass.